# Start different scripts from script

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I would like to have several scripts running on PythonAnywhere. In order to make sure that the scripts are not killed I would like to check for their status in an interval of five minutes (based on https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/LongRunningTasks/).

Two questions arise:
1. In the script which runs every five minutes I would like to check whether the other scripts (script2, script3) are still alive or not. If not, I would obviously like to run them. But how do I run several scripts from one script (script1) without script1 getting "stuck"? I.e. how do I start two scripts at the same time from one script?

2. If I just try to run the script using "import script2" I get an error

> ImportError: No module named script2

How do I tell Python that the script is in a different folder (because that has to be the issue)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here's some resources that contain the answers to your questions: [Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) is about structuring python projects, [Multithreading](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm) is about running multiple sections of your code at once, and [os.system](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) tells you how to start another program separately from your main program.

Comment: Thanks, problem already solved. First, I had to change the permissions of the file(s), second, I used something like:
 p = subprocess.Popen("python3.7 folder/script.py", preexec_fn=os.setsid, shell=True)

This way the process is started as subprocess and doesn't get killed when the mother process is killed.

Comment: Cool. Read up some docs before running to SO in the future, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import time
import subprocess 

def check_process(proc,path):    
    if proc.poll()!=1:
        print('%s still running' % proc)
    elif proc.poll()==1:#will give a 1 if the child process has been killed
        print('%s is dead. Re-running')
        subprocess.Popen(['python.exe', path])

script1=subprocess.Popen(['python.exe', pathscript1])
script2=subprocess.Popen(['python.exe', pathscript2])

while True:
    check_process(script1,pathscript1)
    check_process(script2,pathscript2)
    time.sleep(300)
```